# How to overlap divs using CSS?

Tags: html, css

What I have is a user profile container that contains a head, a body (with two inner body section) and a footer that contains a photo.

[image]

I am looking for a way to make the divs overlapped so the first div at the left will be fixed and each next div will be overlap on the previous one like this one:

[image]

Here what I have

HTML

```
<div class="userContainer">
    <div class="userHead">
        Head
    </div>
    <div class="userBody">
        <div class="userBody1">
            Body 1
        </div>
        <div class="userBody2">
            Body 2
        </div>
        <div class="userImage">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="userContainer">
    <div class="userHead">
        Head
    </div>
    <div class="userBody">
        <div class="userBody1">
            Body 1
        </div>
        <div class="userBody2">
            Body 2
        </div>
        <div class="userImage">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.userContainer {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    height:100px !important;
}

.userHead {
    background-color: #f05624;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.userBody {
    width: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 150px;
    border-top-left-radius: 150px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

.userBody1 {
    height: 25%;
    border-top-right-radius: 150px;
    border-top-left-radius: 150px;
    background-color: #f05624;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.userBody2 {
    height: 15%;
    background-color: #f05624;
    font-size: 10px !important;
}

.userImage img{
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Check [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/edqpyvs1/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the attribute `z-index` an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another line of css, explicilty setting the first containers left margin to 0 px.

```
.userContainer:nth-child(1){
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Set your other container margins to margin-left -20px

```
.userContainer {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    height:100px !important;
    margin-left:-30px;
}
```

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/edqpyvs1/2/

### Updated solution:

Add this JS code to make sure that the container has a greater z-index that the next container etc...

```
var containers = document.getElementsByClassName("userContainer");

var zindexvalue = 1000;

for(index = containers.length - 1 ; index >= 0; index--){
  var container = containers[index];
  container.style.zIndex = zindexvalue;
  zindexvalue = zindexvalue + 1;
}
```

**### Check it out.**

Answer (score 0):

You could nest div2 inside div1:

```
<div id="div1">
    <img src="\img1.png" />

    <div id="div2">
        <img src="\img1.png" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using z-index: https://jsfiddle.net/edqpyvs1/1/

```
.userContainer {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    height:100px !important;
    z-index: 100;
}
.userContainer + .userContainer{
    z-index: 99;
    left: -50px;
}
```